# CSS2 selectors and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, css-selectors

I'd like to use CSS2 selectors ( `parent > child`, `element:first-child`, etc) in my stylesheet but IE6 doesn't seem to recognize those. Is there any plugin (jQuery preferably) that would allow me to use pseudo-selectors freely without worrying about the damned IE6?

Comment: You could just not worry about the damned IE6 in general.  ;)

Comment: Wish I could, but the client needs IE6 support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

The [Super Selectors](http://sandbox.skulljackpot.com/superselectors/demo/) jQuery plugin scans the page's styles for selectors which aren't supported by all browsers and then adds apropriate classes to elements that those CSS3 selectors are targeting.

You can also look at this CSS3 selectors for IE5/IE8 called [ie-css3.js](http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/ie-css3/)

Comment: I already use jQuery (which comes with sizzle), but I want something that would allow me to use pseudo-selecotors freely on my css stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend against using javascript to fix those kind of problems.

The best approach I've found is using [conditional](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) [comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) and create a [IE only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(VS.85).aspx) CSS file, optimized for that <sub>hellish</sub> browser.

In the long run, the small duplication of work is compensated by the smaller amount of incompatibilities that you'd have to correct between sane browsers and IE.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, I go with [adding classNames to the body tag via conditional comments](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) as my preferred method to deal with cross-browser difficulties.

However, if that's out and if *performance is not a concern*, you can always give Dean Edwards's excellent [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) a try. It will parse and grok your stylesheet, picking out and implementing those unsupported selectors.

Beware that, as your stylesheets increase and size and complexity, the script's (and your site's) performance will suffer in IE6. However, in a lot of cases things should run just fine. Make sure to conditionally comment it in for IE6 and below and you'll be set.